# Sequential Attribute on a class level nunit

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit

Is there something similar to [`Sequential Attribute`](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=sequential&r=2.5) that I can put on the class itself.
And use the  Sequential variables on the class level and not on a specific test level as it works with `Sequential Attribute`.

I just have to run TestFixtureSetUp related to the combination of the variables we are using .

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [Parameterized Test Fixtures](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testFixture&r=2.5)? You could pass the list of parameters in your TestFixture c'tor, e.g:

```
[TestFixture("hello", "hello", "goodbye")]
[TestFixture("zip", "zip")]
[TestFixture(42, 42, 99)]
public class ParameterizedTestFixture
{
    private string eq1;
    private string eq2;
    private string neq;

    public ParameterizedTestFixture(string eq1, string eq2, string neq)
    {
        this.eq1 = eq1;
        this.eq2 = eq2;
        this.neq = neq;
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestEquality()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(eq1, eq2);
        if (eq1 != null && eq2 != null)
            Assert.AreEqual(eq1.GetHashCode(), eq2.GetHashCode());
    }
}
```